# Sql Server aggregate concatenate CLR returning different sequence of strings based on number of records

Tags: sql-server, clr

I have a clr aggregate concatenation function, similar to https://gist.github.com/FilipDeVos/5b7b4addea1812067b09. When the number of rows are small, the sequence of concatenated strings follows the input data set. When the number of rows are larger (dozens and more), the sequence seems indeterminate. There is a difference in the execution plan, but I'm not that familiar with the optimizer and what hints to apply (I've tried MAXDOP 1, without success). From a different test than the example below with similar results here's what seems to be the difference in the plan - the separate sorts, then a merge join. The row count where it tipped over here was 60.

yielded expected results:
[image]

yielded unexpected results:
[image]

Below is the query that demonstrates the issue in the AdventureWorks2014 sample database with the above clr (renamed to TestConcatenate). The intended result is a dataset with a row for each order and a column with a delimited list of products for that order in quantity sequence.

```
 ;with cte_ordered_steps AS (
  SELECT top 100000 sd.SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID, OrderQty
  FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] sd
  --WHERE sd.SalesOrderID IN (53598, 53595)
  ORDER BY sd.SalesOrderID, OrderQty
  )

 select
  sd.SalesOrderID,
  dbo.TestConcatenate(' QTY: ' + CAST(sd.OrderQty AS VARCHAR(9)) + ': ' + IsNull(p.Name, '')) 
 FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] sd
 JOIN [Production].[Product] p ON p.ProductID = sd.ProductID
 JOIN cte_ordered_steps r ON r.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID AND r.SalesOrderDetailID = sd.SalesOrderDetailID
 where sd.SalesOrderID IN (53598, 53595)
 GROUP BY sd.SalesOrderID
```

When the SalesOrderID is constrained in the cte for 53598, 53595, the sequence is correct (top set), when it's constrained in the main select for 53598, 53595, the sequence is not (botton set). 
[image]

So what's my question? How can I build the query, with hints or other changes to return consistent (and correct) sequenced concatenated values  independent of the number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Just like a normal query, if there isn't an order by clause, return order isn't guaranteed. If I recall correctly, the SQL 92 spec allows for an order by clause to be passed in to an aggregate via an over clause, SQL Server doesn't implement it. So there's no way to guarantee ordering in your CLR function (unless you implement it yourself by collecting everything in the `Accumulate` and `Merge` methods into some sort of collection and then sorting the list in the `Terminate` method before returning it. But you'll pay a cost in terms of memory grants as now need to serialize the collection.

As to why you're seeing different behavior based on the size of your result set, I notice that a different join operator is being used between the two. A loop join and a merge join walk through the two sets being joined differently and so that might account for the difference you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the aggregate dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_S available at http://groupconcat.codeplex.com. The S is for Sorted output. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

While this answer doesn't have a solution, the additional information that Ben and Orlando provided (thanks!) have provided what I need to move on. I'll take the approach that Orlando pointed to, which was also my plan B, i.e. sorting in the clr.